# Download android command line tools from url

Tags: android, download

When I download the command line tools based on a URL (for example: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip), why is there always the "latest" designation at the end of every URL? I provide a specific version, but still, the "latest" is appended to all of them. I would like to know why?

Comment: because the "latest" is included in the name shown in Android SDK manager. Do ask my why, but it is as it is.